# Disable controls in previous step

Tags: c#, asp.net, wizard

how can I disable all checbkoxes or all radiobuttons in previous step of wizard after nextbuttonclick event?

Comment: Did you tried anythind? Please read [faq] and [ask]

Comment: Your question has the answer, disable all controls on clicking next in Wizard if your operation was success

Comment: Wow, awesome answers. I know I have to do it in OnNextButtonClick event. But I'm asking how to find these controls after moving to next step and disable them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:Wizard ID="Wizard1" runat="server" 
        onnextbuttonclick="Wizard1_NextButtonClick">
        <WizardSteps>
            <asp:WizardStep ID="Step1" runat="server" Title="Step 1">
                <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" Text="Option 1" runat="server" />
                <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" Text="Option 2" runat="server" />
                <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton3" Text="Option 3" runat="server" />
            </asp:WizardStep>
            <asp:WizardStep ID="Step2" runat="server" Title="Step 2">
            </asp:WizardStep>
        </WizardSteps>
    </asp:Wizard>
```

**Code behind:**

```
protected void Wizard1_NextButtonClick(object sender, WizardNavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (Wizard1.ActiveStep == Step1)
    {
        IEnumerable<RadioButton> controls = FindControls<RadioButton>(Step1);
        controls.ToList().ForEach(c => c.Enabled = false);
    }
}

IEnumerable<T> FindControls<T>(Control parent) where T : Control
{
    foreach (Control c in parent.Controls)
    {
        if (c.GetType() == typeof(T)) yield return (T)c;
        foreach (var subControl in FindControls<T>(c))
            yield return subControl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Deni. It doesn't work for me. The thing I need is to use it to disable controls if user goes to the next step and then clicks previous page button in his browser - in that case controls in step before should be disabled. Do you have any idea how to do this?

Comment: The logic to get the controls and disable them definitely works.I think the problem is that you're not sure at which point to actually disable the controls.If you want to disable them when the user clicks on the Previous button implement `OnPreviousButtonClick` event for the Wizzard.Ultimately I would suggest getting more familiar with the Wizzard by reading it's msdn documentation - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.wizard(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've checked and it doesn't work, when `step.allowreturn=false`.